# Dynamically display table in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to dynamically display a table in Angular, depending on the info coming from the DB

So far, I have this Info

```
[ { "BET": 57630343, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true },
  { "BET": 57633044, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true },
  { "BET": 57633047, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true },
  { "BET": 57635034, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true } ]
```

everything with `XX...` should be a `button`

and in the HTML

```
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Bet</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Fill Open Bet</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="pendingBet in pendingBets">
            <td> {{::pendingBet.BET}}</td>
            <td> {{::pendingBet.CUSTOMER}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Fill</button></td> <!--{{pendingBet.XX_FILL_OPEN}}-->
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

the issue I have here is: above I have something static like

```
            <th>Bet</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Fill Open Bet</th>
```

but sometimes `<th>Bet</th>` which is `<td> {{::pendingBet.BET}}</td>` is not coming from the DB, so I don't have to display it, so I want to know what should I do to display it dynamically

what should I do in this case?

**EDIT**

Let explain myself better:

according to the table, `<td> {{::pendingBet.BET}}</td>` belongs to `<th>Bet</th>`, but sometimes `pendingBet.BET` is `null` so I don't have to display all that column `<th>Bet</th>` and `<td> {{::pendingBet.BET}}</td>`, the same with `Customer` and `Fill Open`.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you wanting to remove the whole column if none of the rows have `pendingBet.BET`?

Comment: @charlietfl yes. I `BET`, or `CUSTOMER` or the other are not coming from the DB, then I should not display that row neither the header.

Comment: Oh... just row...can use `ng-if` on the `<tr>` for that. Or filter the data first in controller

Comment: @charlietfl why on the `<tr>` ? is doesn't make any sense, if I apply to the whole `<tr>`, then when BET isn't coming, nothing will show up.

Comment: Then it is not clear what you are expecting

Comment: @charlietfl look at my update please

Comment: for whole column you would need to loop through all the data first to see if any rows have values for that column. Use column counters and don't show column if it is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` on the `<th>` and `<td>`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-if="hasBetColumn">Bet</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Fill Open Bet</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="pendingBet in pendingBets">
        <td ng-if="hasBetColumn"> {{::pendingBet.BET}}</td>
        <td> {{::pendingBet.CUSTOMER}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Fill</button></td> <!--{{pendingBet.XX_FILL_OPEN}}-->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

It's up to you to determine how you want to set `hasBetColumn`, either in your controller or as part of the returned data from your API call.

Answer (score 1):

If all the fields are dynamic:

In you ctrl, you need a array to store the fields you want to display, if you assign it with `Object.keys(data[0])` every time you initialize the ctrl, you may not see the same table because properties order in objects are not guaranteed in js.

in ctrl

```
//Leat's say you have lodash (or underscore, if you dont you should...)
$scope.fields = _.intersection( ["BET", "CUSTOMER", "whatever"],
  _.keys(data ? data[0] : {})
)
```

in html

```
<tbody>  
  <!-- ng-repeat on fields in `thead ` -->
  <tr ng-repeat="pendingBet in pendingBets">
      <td ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-bind="::pendingBet[field]"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: the `<th>` part is also dynamic.

Comment: Yes. just ng-repeat on `$scope.fields` because  `$scope.fields` will be dynamic based on your data's keys.